# How to play sound from a IP in java with Android

Tags: java, android, jmf

I want to run a radio station from a hill top with the studio in the valley using a radio Ethernet link of 1.1 mbs data rate below is an example code (below) that I found.

But I want the code to:

1. Load a text file containing the IPv4 IP address to receive sound
2. Read a true or false from the file re transmit from the android for another to receive to save data on such a slow connection.

Can someone help please?

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Vector;
import javax.media.CaptureDeviceInfo;
import javax.media.CaptureDeviceManager;
import javax.media.DataSink;
import javax.media.Manager;
import javax.media.MediaLocator;
import javax.media.NoPlayerException;
import javax.media.NoProcessorException;
import javax.media.NotRealizedError;
import javax.media.Player;
import javax.media.Processor;
import javax.media.control.FormatControl;
import javax.media.control.TrackControl;
import javax.media.format.AudioFormat;
import javax.media.protocol.ContentDescriptor;
import javax.media.protocol.DataSource;

public class SimpleVoiceTransmiter {

/**
* @param args
*/
public static void main(String[] args) {
// First find a capture device that will capture linear audio
// data at 8bit 8Khz
AudioFormat format= new AudioFormat(AudioFormat.LINEAR, 8000, 8, 1);
Vector devices= CaptureDeviceManager.getDeviceList( format);
CaptureDeviceInfo di= null;

if (devices.size() > 0) {
di = (CaptureDeviceInfo) devices.elementAt( 0);
}
else {
// exit if we could not find the relevant capturedevice.
System.exit(-1);
}

// Create a processor for this capturedevice & exit if we
// cannot create it
Processor processor = null;
try {
processor = Manager.createProcessor(di.getLocator());
} catch (IOException e) {
System.exit(-1);
} catch (NoProcessorException e) {
System.exit(-1);
}

// configure the processor 
processor.configure();

while (processor.getState() != Processor.Configured){
try {
Thread.sleep(100);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
e.printStackTrace();
}
}

processor.setContentDescriptor(
new ContentDescriptor( ContentDescriptor.RAW));

TrackControl track[] = processor.getTrackControls();

boolean encodingOk = false;

// Go through the tracks and try to program one of them to
// output gsm data.

for (int i = 0; i < track.length; i++) {
if (!encodingOk && track[i] instanceof FormatControl) { 
if (((FormatControl)track[i]).
setFormat( new AudioFormat(AudioFormat.GSM_RTP, 8000, 8, 1)) == null) {

track[i].setEnabled(false);
}
else {
encodingOk = true;
}
} else {
// we could not set this track to gsm, so disable it
track[i].setEnabled(false);
}
}

// At this point, we have determined where we can send out
// gsm data or not.
// realize the processor
if (encodingOk) {
processor.realize();
while (processor.getState() != Processor.Realized){
try {
Thread.sleep(100);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
e.printStackTrace();
}
}
// get the output datasource of the processor and exit
// if we fail
DataSource ds = null;

try {
ds = processor.getDataOutput();
} catch (NotRealizedError e) {
System.exit(-1);
}

// hand this datasource to manager for creating an RTP
// datasink our RTP datasink will multicast the audio
try {
String url= "rtp://224.0.0.1:22224/audio/16";

MediaLocator m = new MediaLocator(url);

DataSink d = Manager.createDataSink(ds, m);
d.open();
d.start();
processor.start();
} catch (Exception e) {
System.exit(-1);
} 
} 
}
}
```

Receiver:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import javax.media.Manager;
import javax.media.MediaLocator;
import javax.media.NoPlayerException;
import javax.media.Player;

public class SimpleVoiceReciver{

/**
* @param args
*/
public static void main(String[] args) {
String url= "rtp://192.168.1.111:22224/audio/16";

MediaLocator mrl= new MediaLocator(url);

if (mrl == null) {
System.err.println("Can't build MRL for RTP");
System.exit(-1);
}

// Create a player for this rtp session
Player player = null;
try {
player = Manager.createPlayer(mrl);
} catch (NoPlayerException e) {
System.err.println("Error:" + e);
System.exit(-1);
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
System.err.println("Error:" + e);
System.exit(-1);
} catch (IOException e) {
System.err.println("Error:" + e);
System.exit(-1);
}

if (player != null) {
System.out.println("Player created.");
player.realize();
// wait for realizing
while (player.getState() != Player.Realized){
try {
Thread.sleep(10);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
}
player.start();
} else {
System.err.println("Player doesn't created.");
System.exit(-1);
}
}

}
```

Comment: Why is the formatting all wonkey-jawed?

Comment: This sounds like an interesting project, what do you need help with?

Comment: What is the true/false bit supposed to do exactly?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds perfectly possible to do this multicasting over a local network. AFAIK this will **not** work across the internet. Also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3623143/multicast-on-android-2-2) : Device support for multicasting is apparently very patchy. So do your research, and make sure the Android devices you work with actually support this on a software and hardware level - many of them do not. Caveat Emptor.