# Want to send data one to many using UDP

Tags: android, udp, file-transfer

I want to send data from one device to many devices using UDP without using IP address of the destination devices. http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/simple-udp-communication-example
i refereed this link but they used ip address, i don't want to use any ip address. any idea how to do.

Comment: You want do a multicast. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3623143/multicast-on-android-2-2 for implementation in Android.

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot use any IP Address, its better to use Push Notification using [GCM](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/index.html).

When ever you need to broadcast something, just need to send a message to GCM Server, which will notify the clients which has suscribed for this type of message.